# How to create optional router argument in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I am have a router configuration shown below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'Registration',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    children: [
      { path:'',component:ProfileComponent},
      { path: 'Dependent', component: DependentComponent },
      { path: 'Matrimony', component: MatrimonyComponent },
      { path: 'Subscription', component: MagazinesubscriptionComponent },
      { path: 'Donation', component: DonationComponent }
        ]
  },
  {
    path: 'Profile',
     component: ProfilelistComponent
    //component: VoteprofileComponent
  }
];
```

This same router i want to use for editing. Mean like shown below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'Registration/:id',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    children: [
      { path:'',component:ProfileComponent},
      { path: 'Dependent', component: DependentComponent },
      { path: 'Matrimony', component: MatrimonyComponent },
      { path: 'Subscription', component: MagazinesubscriptionComponent },
      { path: 'Donation', component: DonationComponent }
        ]
  },
  {
    path: 'Profile',
     component: ProfilelistComponent
    //component: VoteprofileComponent
  }
];
```

Is there anyway in angular without replicating the complete route config I can achieve.

Mean i can specify the parameter as optional?

Comment: You have to specify the route, otherwise how would angular know where to route to. And your 2nd routing config looks weird.

Comment: @penleychan Thanks for replying, Yes just a copy paste issue. I corrected it. Can i do it without replicating the child route. Some way i can make :Id as optional

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of a way to make the parameter optional. Depending on what you're trying to achieve you could use a specific string you could detect in the id param (Registration/new vs Registration/678A6).

Anyway the routes are just plain typescript so I guess you could keep it dry this way:

```
const registrationRouteConfig = {
  component: RegisterComponent,
  children: [
    { path:'',component:ProfileComponent},
    { path: 'Dependent', component: DependentComponent },
    { path: 'Matrimony', component: MatrimonyComponent },
    { path: 'Subscription', component: MagazinesubscriptionComponent },
    { path: 'Donation', component: DonationComponent }
  ]
}

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'Registration', ...registrationRouteConfig },
   { path: 'Registration/:id', ...registrationRouteConfig },
   { path: 'Profile', component: ProfilelistComponent }
]
```

Comment: I used the technique described in this answer: define the route with and without the "optional" route parameter.  In the Component's ngOnInit() I'm extracting the parameter value to a field.  In the view I check the field for undefined as well what I have decided should be the 'default' value, treating them the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way (I didn't test it)
If you make a module, and add the below items in that module routing

```
  { path:'',component:ProfileComponent},
  { path: 'Dependent', component: DependentComponent },
  { path: 'Matrimony', component: MatrimonyComponent },
  { path: 'Subscription', component: MagazinesubscriptionComponent },
  { path: 'Donation', component: DonationComponent }
```

Then you can reuse it in app.routing like

```
{   path: 'Registration',   loadChildren: 'pathToYourModule#ModuleName'  },
{   path: 'Registration/:id',   loadChildren: 'pathToYourModule#ModuleName'  },
{   path: 'Profile',   component: ProfilelistComponent }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'users/:id/:name?', component: UserDetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```